# Compare hsqldb and mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc, hsqldb

I have been using HSQLDB for a while now for my small projects as a part of academic requirement. Now I am about to start my career as an enterprise java developer. The organisation where i work use MYSQL. As far as JDBC is concerned, How is it different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as JDBC is concerned, there is no real difference. Of course you'll use a different JDBC driver, and the databases don't have the same features, nor the exact same SQL dialect.

The MySQL JDBC driver also has specific features and configuration options that other JDBC drivers don't have. The most important thing to know about those special "features", IMO, is that by default, MySQL loads all the rows returned by a query in memory, instead of streaming them like all the other drivers do. This can thus cause memory issues if you're loading a lot of data from the database.

Comment: so if i change my driver, and driver specific part of my code, then can i use the same code again to run the entire application with new database?